# PCF App to App Oauth 2 grant_type = 'client_credentials' and scope uaa.resources. Local testing

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I have created an app on PCF for Oauth 2 with `grant_type = 'client_credentials'` and scope `uaa.resources`. How do I test it in local without calling the actual URLs?

Answer (score 0):

It can be tested in 2 ways:

1. Using Postman Oauth 2.0 Flow
2. Using jwt.io

Once you get the token, pass it in the endpoint and you will be able to hit services and will be able to see json object.

(Eurekha can also be used to test)